# having issues with a form trying to use jquery to ajax only the $the_message field to avoid browser refresh

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to avoid the browser refresh and get to display only the message without the browser refresh.

```
    $idc = $_GET['id'];
    $name1 = $_GET['name'];
    $id2 = $_GET['ids'];
     if ($_POST['message_field'] != ""){
        $message_field = $_POST['message_field'];

          $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment (mem_id,commented_men_id, message, message_date) 
         VALUES('$userid','$idc','$message_field', now())")  
         or die (mysql_error());

    }

        $sql_message = mysql_query("SELECT id, mem_id ,message, message_date FROM comment WHERE mem_id='$userid'  ORDER BY message_date DESC");

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_message)){


            $id = $row["id"];
            $me_id = $row["mem_id"];
            $json = $row["message"];
                 $message_date = $row["message_date"];
                $message = json_encode($json);

 $sql_mem_data = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM users WHERE  id='$me_id'");
              while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_mem_data)){
                $id = $row2["id"];
                $ufirstname = $row2["name"];
        }

    $messageList .= '<div id="only"><p>' . ufirstname . '</p><br/><p    id="pmessage">'.$the_message.'</p></div>';

    }

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title> Book</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mootools-core-1.3.2-full-compat.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

       $("#messageinput").click(function() {
           $.post($('#message').attr("action"),
                  $("#message").serialize(),
                  function(html) {
                    var comment = $(html) .find('#messageoutput').html();
                      $("#pmessage").html(comment);
              });
   });
       });

    </script>
         <div id="messageid">
             <form align="left" id="message" action="<?php profile.php?id='.$idc.'& ids='.    $id2.'&name='.$name1.'?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="blab_from">
        <textarea name="message_field" rows="3" style="width:97%;"></textarea>
         <input id="messageinput" name="submit" type="button" value="submit" align="left" />
        </form>
        </div>
        <div id="messageoutput"><?php print "$messageList"; ?></div>
```

Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blabbing` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mem_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `commented_men_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `the_message` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sub_commented_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=146 ;
```

Comment: i want to avoid browser refresh right now the comment is submited but then it will repeat the entire site inside the id #pmessage instead of only displaying the message only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prevent default submit action to do that you can use `preventDefault`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#messageinput").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
       $.post($('#message').attr("action"),
              $("#message").serialize(),
              function(html) {
                  $("#pmessage").html(html);
              }
       );
   });
</script>
```

Also please end the script tag

Comment: some how still this is causing the whole site to print inside the #pmessage doubling it. instead of just printing the message inside this id tag

Comment: it is printing everything is inside the html tags inside the #pmessage like repeating the whole thing. when I only need the messsage to display only no the entire site in this id tag called #pmessage. what could be happening?

Comment: Its happening because you are using the same file as a target of post. So what you can use a different file to save the info in db and which will print success message only. For example create another file named `save_profile.php` which will have database saving part and use it in form action.

Comment: ok and inside that file I should query the message instead of querying in the same file? I mean if I will select query inside the save_profile.php

Comment: TApos I will have to have the INSERT and the SELECT in this new file?

Comment: I think you will need the select in the same file too as this is used at very first to show. Better create a function for select the data.

Comment: Select in the file above? and in the save_profile.php. please can you provide a squema or order in what you are talking about to direct me in the way 
?

Comment: 1. You need to show message input form.  Not sure if you need message output at first. If so then you need need `SELECT` sql in profile.php, 2. jquery will post data to save_profile.php,3. Save the profile (`insert` statement) and select the message again (in this case you will need `select` statement) 3. You will get the response from save_profile.php and show it in message output.

Comment: message input form in profile.php? and then in save_profile.php. I will need a whole schema if you could provide one it will greatly appriciated man.

Comment: @fello, sorry .. didn't get enough time to do the codes. Can you please send your `comment` table schema.

Comment: hey Tapos, thanks for replying back the structure is as above